# How to make the "frequency" bold in \NMR command of the chemmacros package?

Tags: bold, sharelatex, chemmacros

I am using the \NMR command of the chemmacros package. The format is bold. But as you see in the picture, the frequency "500 MHz" is not bold.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=spectroscopy}
\begin{document}

\begin{experimental}[format=\bfseries,delta=(ppm),list=true,use-equal=true]
\NMR(500)[DMSO-\textit{d}6] \val{1.05} (s, \#{3}, \J(3;H,H){3}, \pos{4}), \val{3.05} (t, \#{3}, \J(4;H,H){7}, \pos{3})
\end{experimental}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make the frequency also bold? I have tried it like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=spectroscopy}
\begin{document}

\begin{experimental}[format=\bfseries,delta=(ppm),list=true,use-equal=true]
\NMR(\textbf{500})[DMSO-\textit{d}6] \val{1.05} (s, \#{3}, \J(3;H,H){3}, \pos{4}), \val{3.05} (t, \#{3}, \J(4;H,H){7}, \pos{3})
\end{experimental}
\end{document}
```

But this gives me an error. In the documentation of the package the frequency is also bold, when you write "format=\bfseries". So this could not help me. I am using "ShareLaTeX".

Thanks.

Comment: `\sisetup{detect-weight}`, if you want to answer @clemens.

Answer (score 1):

`chemmacros` use `siunitx` for typesetting values and units. (In particular, the section in the manual about the spectroscopy module starts with “The `spectroscopy` module loads the `chemformula` module and the `siunitx` package”.)

The `siunitx` package typesets everything as upright (usually non-bold) text. The last paragraph of the section “`siunitx` for the impatient” says:

> By default, all text is typeset in the current upright math font.

The manual has comprehensive sections about this behaviour. In short: in your case you need to either use the `detect-weight` (for only detecting and adapting to the current font weight) or the `detect-all` option (for detecting and adaptiong to all current font properties):

```
\sisetup{detect-weight}
```

or

```
\sisetup{detect-all}
```